# How to do MVVM Light data binding in non english cultures?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I cannot get data binding in MVVM light to work with numbers for non english cultures. The view model has a decimal property and I want the bound input textbox to handle validation and input according to the current culture.

Is that not supported or is there an easy work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default culture for WPF UI Elements is en-us. If you want to change this, this might help:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
            someCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Where `someCulture` is the culture you want to use for your UI (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for the current one). You should call this in `Application.Startup`, before any UI elements get created.